# Display protocol in Safari address bar

Tags: safari

Currently Safari shows the url of the open page without mentioning the protocol:

> apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Is there a way to have Safari show the protocol in the address bar:

> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Not that I know off, but you'll see a https tag for secure connections (so there is a visual indicator), and when you copy the entire address it will include the protocol as well.

Comment: I am not seeing the https tag in some pages although when I copy the URL it does include https as the protocol.

Comment: That sounds unlikely, do you have any example?

Comment: I'll have to research this more by looking at the com.apple.Safari.plist file, but normally settings like these that aren't in the UI are sometimes available to change with the defaults command in the Terminal app. (this won't work on iOS AFAIK).

Answer (score 6):

You can temporarily display the protocol by activating the address bar with <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> and copy-pasting the current URL back to the address bar with <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.

The protocol will, however, disappear again as soon as you load a new page by following a link on the page or pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the address bar.

Answer (score 2):

Normally settings like these that aren't in the UI are sometimes available to change with the defaults command in the Terminal app.  (this won't work on iOS AFAIK).

Unfortunately though, it doesn't appear there is any setting for this:

```
teak:~ mhp$ defaults read com.apple.Safari | grep -i protocol 
teak:~ mhp$ defaults read com.apple.Safari | grep -i url
    DidMigrateToMoreRestrictiveFileURLPolicy = 1; 
teak:~ mhp$ defaults read com.apple.Safari | grep -i address 
teak:~ mhp$ defaults read com.apple.Safari | grep -i http
```

I also looked through all the [settings that other people have posted](http://secrets.blacktree.com/?showapp=com.apple.Safari) on the net and found no options.